# Get API key and secret key via Shopify API?

Tags: api, e-commerce, shopify

I'm a beginner Shopify developer. I would like to create my application for Shopify store (not private). I want to show api_key and secret_key after installation plugin by merchant. I viewed a lot of tutorials and all of them looks like get this values from nothing. That's why I want to know the answer on 1 question:

1) Is it possible to retrieve from Shopify API api_key and secret_key for application?

I'll be very appreciate, if someone helps me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot retrieve your App's App key and Secret through a Shopify API call.

Those keys are used for authorizing your app to be able to gain API access on a particular shop. They are something particular to your app and you don't need an API call for it.

You can find those keys on your App listing on your Shopify Partner account.

This is confirmed by the [Shopify API documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/api) where it doesn't mention you can do this.

Comment: Thank you. I understood this. But I see some examples in Shopify tutorials, where throught the code user can get access to the API_KEY and SECRET_KEY as environment varibales (e.g. SHOPIFY_API_KEY = os.environ.get('SHOPIFY_API_KEY')
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET = os.environ.get('SHOPIFY_API_SECRET') for python). Is this feature is just available for applications with embedded SDK? If so, maybe exits some workaround for aplication developed on Java for example? I don't want to ask user copy API_KEY manually and    insert these parameters to application settings.

Comment: In those examples, they are essentially telling you to load your Key and Secret as environment variables when you deploy your application. For example, I have an app deployed on Heroku and I have those keys stored in the environment variables there named both SHOPIFY_API_KEY  and SHOPIFY_API_SECRET. On Django, I get to access them using os.environment.get() so that I don't have to store them in my source code. Your app end user should haven no access to them at all. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I try to use best practice from top applications from Shopify AppStore. I found example of one popular app, which, as I understood, was written using not embedded SDK. This application, after installation redirects me to the external url, and in settings tab on the app site I can find my API key, shared key. I would like to achieve the same behaviour. Maybe do you know how is it possible?

Comment: I'm almost certain that those are keys for something else. You should never give your Shopify app key and secret. And if you think about it, there is no purpose to giving it to them, they really have no use for them. You already have the access token to query the API from their store. I hope that this helps.

Comment: Ok. Thank a lot for your patience. It seems, that I don't understand confirming installation step from Shopify documentation. I understood that I has to verify hmac, hostname and nonce. Let's imagine that all of them are correct, for getting permanent access token I has to send POST request with harcoded API-key, API-secret for my application (Am I right about deriviation of api-key nad api-secret)?